# each 10 cell is repeated TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, avplayer

I'm working with the `AVPlayer` inside the `UITableView`.  When I change the image buttons each 10 cell repe. Why each 10 cell is repeated and how fix it? Pay attention to the superclass.

```
  var boolValue = false

 class TableViewControllerAudioList: UIView,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var avplayer:AVPlayer!




override func setNeedsDisplay() {
    super.setNeedsDisplay()


}



 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return modalsF.count
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellAudioList


    cell.name.text = modalsF[indexPath.row].AudioName
    cell.duration.text = "00:00"
    cell.number.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"

    cell.playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)


    cell.playChange.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.playChange.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tickClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.tapAction = { (cell) in







   // self.player = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file: "https:----.com" + modalsF[indexPath.row].UrlName! as NSString, type: "mp3")

    self.avplayer = self.pl(file: "https:---.com" + modalsF[indexPath.row].UrlName! as NSString)


       // self.play(tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!.row)

        }


     return cell
}



func tickClicked(_ sender: UIButton!) {
    print(sender.tag)
    let cellTop = tableView.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0) as IndexPath) as!TableViewCellAudioList

    if boolValue == false{
        cellTop.playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        boolValue = true
    } else {
        cellTop.playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        boolValue = false
    }
}




func pl(file:NSString) -> AVPlayer? {

    let url = URL(string: file as String)
    let avPlayer: AVPlayer?
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)



    if avPlayer?.rate == 0 {
        avPlayer?.play()
        avPlayer?.rate = 1.0

    } else if avPlayer?.rate == 1{

        avPlayer?.pause()

    }

    return avPlayer

}
```

TableViewCell:

```
class TableViewCellAudioList: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var number: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var duration: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playChange: UIButton!



var tapAction: ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?
@IBAction func playAudio(_ sender: Any) {
    tapAction?(self) 
  }    
}
```

Comment: have you try to add `cell.tag = indexPath.row` with if condition

Comment: Your table code looks okay. Are you sure that `modalsF` is not the source of your trouble?

Comment: @LarryOBrien ModalsF stores data

Answer (score 1):

In your `tableView(_: cellForRowAt:)` you set up the:

- `cell.name.text`
- `cell.duration.text`
- `cell.number.text`
- `cell.playChange.tag`

for each new cell, so those values are updated when the cell is reused with new content.

But you do not change the image of your `playChange` button back, so it won't be updated when you reuse the cell.

When you tap your `playChange` button you update the image of the button in `tickClicked`. So when `tickClicked` is called on one of your cells, the image is updated, and you don't change it back later when you reuse the cell.

Try changing the value/image/state of your `playChange` button in `tableView(_: cellForRowAt:)`.

And also, have a look at the method [`prepareForReuse`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) of `UITableViewCell`. This method is called before the cell is reused and gives you a chance to "reset" the cell.

Notice though, as it says in the documentation:

> For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table view's delegate in 
>   tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)
>    should always reset all content when reusing a cell.

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` re-uses old tableview cells if it can.

You don't set the `playChange` image in the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. So it re-uses the image that was already there in the original tableview cell.

Comment: i set playChange image. cell don't save image when scroll, Gif in question

Comment: In the code you show, you do not use `cell.playChange.setImage` in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. That means the re-used cell still has the old image in it.

Comment: With the changed code, you have a different problem. In `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` you need to set the image of the cell to what is applicable to that cell. That is, you need to keep track of which song(s) are playing. Then set the image of the cell to "play.png" or "pause.png", depending on whether that song is playing or not.